# Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: CustomRenderShrinkWrappingViewport#f6727 relayoutBoundary=up17 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING

Tags: flutter, widget

I need to generate a list horizontally. But, I'm facing the following issue:

> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was
> fired: CustomRenderShrinkWrappingViewport#f6727 relayoutBoundary=up17
> NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:   needs
> compositing   creator: CustomShrinkWrappingViewport ←
> IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#952f0] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
> _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey#f0fc7] ←
> Listener ← _ScrollableScope ← _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#c0651] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ←
> RepaintBoundary ← ⋯   parentData:  (can use size)   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=331.2, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)   size:
> MISSING   axisDirection: right   crossAxisDirection: down   offset:
> ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#c3ca2(offset: 0.0, range: null..null,
> viewport: null,
> ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics -> RangeMaintainingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#d7dd2,
> ScrollDirection.idle)   anchor: 0.0 This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
> child 0: RenderSliverPadding#963bb NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: RenderSliverList#5357f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
> child 1: RenderSliverPadding#2291f NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
> child: RenderSliverList#6db77 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>
> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out:
> CustomRenderShrinkWrappingViewport#f6727 relayoutBoundary=up17
> NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

**The Code Is:**

```
CustomScrollView(
      // physics: ScrollPhysics(),
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,

      slivers: [
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (context, index) => ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemScrollController: _scrollController,
              itemCount: dummyQuestions.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              currentPageIndex = index;
              return dummyQuestions[index];
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please Refer Below Code:

```
CustomScrollView(
      controller: scrollController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (_, int index) {
             return Container(
             child: Text(list[index]['index'],),
             );
            },
            childCount: list.length,
          )
        ),
      ],
    ))
```

Comment: It doesn't really explain how it fixes the problem, and what is happening ^^'